# How can I find $\delta$ given $\epsilon$?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, math-software, piecewise-continuity

How do I need to show that there exist $\delta>0$ corresponding to $\epsilon= 0.03$, when $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit. Given that $f(x,y,z)$ is
$$f(x,y,z)=\tan^2 x + \tan^2 y + \tan^2 z.$$

Comment: Why this $z$ ??

Comment: I tried to say that but was not sure how to stretch the comment to 15 characters.

Comment: Thanks, now I know.

Comment: @Sumit Please check if my edit is correct.

Comment: Its absolutely correct. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

This plot of $\dfrac{\tan x}x$ shows you that you can ensure $c_0|t|\le|\tan t|\le c_1|t|$ in your favorite range around $0$ ($c_0=1,c_1=\tan x_{\max}/x_{\max}$). With this you can easily bound.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but would you please elaborate till finding a delta corresponding to epsilon=0.03. Please I need to understand it.

Comment: @Sumit: could you solve for the function $x^2+y^2+z^2$ ?

Comment: yes I can for $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Comment: @Sumit: so you could for $c_1^2x^2+c_1^2y^2+c_1^2z^2$, couldn't you ?

Comment: yup, I can. Thanks